# moving files in zhs terminal beginner question

Tags: mac, macbook

I was trying to move a file called "peakpx (1).jpg" from Downloads to a new directory that I created called thenew however it didn't let me move it with `mv ~/Downloads "peakpx (1).jpg" ~/Downloads/thenew` however it did not work stating loads/: Invalid argument, I tried it without the quotation marks and it still did not work.
Then somehow I pressed tab after writing peakpx and somehow it transformed it to `mv ~/Downloads/peakpx\ \(1\).jpg ~/Downloads/thenew`  and now it did move it to the directory of thenew but not just that file but it took with it other files named similarly too. By pressing `ls` on `thenew` it now contained `peakpx (1).jpg   peakpx (2).jpg  peakpx.jpg` instead of just having peakpx(1).jpg. I wanted to know what happened there, and how should I have moved the file. I'll leave my tries and complete code here Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as I am just starting to learn the terminal.

````
sofiavanessa@MacBook-Air Downloads % mv ~/Downloads/ "peakpx (2).jpg" ~/Downloads/thenew

mv: rename /Users/sofiavanessa/Downloads/ to /Users/sofiavanessa/Downloads/thenew/Downloads/: Invalid argument
mv: peakpx (2).jpg: No such file or directory
sofiavanessa@MacBook-Air Downloads % mv ~/Downloads/ " peakpx (2).jpg " ~/Downloads/thenew

mv: rename /Users/sofiavanessa/Downloads/ to /Users/sofiavanessa/Downloads/thenew/Downloads/: Invalid argument
mv: rename  peakpx (2).jpg  to /Users/sofiavanessa/Downloads/thenew/ peakpx (2).jpg : No such file or directory
sofiavanessa@MacBook-Air Downloads % mv ~/Downloads/ peakpx (2).jpg(.) ~/Downloads/thenew

zsh: no matches found: (2).jpg(.)
sofiavanessa@MacBook-Air Downloads % mv ~/Downloads/peakpx\ \(1\).jpg ~/Downloads/thenew 
sofiavanessa@MacBook-Air Downloads % cd thenew
sofiavanessa@MacBook-Air thenew % ls
peakpx (1).jpg  peakpx (2).jpg  peakpx.jpg
sofiavanessa@MacBook-Air thenew % mv ~/Downloads/thenew "peakpx (1).jpg" ~/Downloads
mv: /Users/sofiavanessa/Downloads/thenew and /Users/sofiavanessa/Downloads/thenew are identical
sofiavanessa@MacBook-Air thenew % ls
peakpx (2).jpg  peakpx.jpg
sofiavanessa@MacBook-Air thenew % cd ..
sofiavanessa@MacBook-Air Downloads % ls
0dcefed4-f293-446c-b514-76bb8c00ab11.jpeg
Critical Thinking Response # 1 .docx
Documento sin título.docx
Feldman Analysis Guidelines .docx
Feldman's Guide.pptx
Install Respondus LockDown Browser (x64c) 168715491.pkg
MAFRAQ CULCHERAL CRENTER BY MOAED SHAWAQFEH.png
googlechrome.dmg
peakpx (1).jpg
peakpx (3).jpg
thenew
sofiavanessa@MacBook-Air Downloads %```
````